# General Peltier (lack of) cooling - why?

Tags: peltier, water

The physics here are beyond simple.

1ml of water requires 4 watts of cooling to drop 1 degree C.

Thus:
30ml x 4W x 33c = 3.96kW (IE cool 30ml by 33c needs 3.96kW of cooling)

The TEC01-02015 spec sheet shows that at even the meager 12V output at max amps available, shows 33c is the rated dT and the Qc is 100 W. It does not say Qc is per per hour or per minute, so we assume it is constant.

3.96kW divided by 100 W/s = 39.6s OK. Round to 40s.

The TEC is well cooled... the cold side is showing -17c in the aluminum water container attached to the cold side.

WHY can't we simply cool 30cl of water without it taking an hour or more? Yeah, sure, there are losses to the ambiance and to the container holding the water (aluminum). What else are we doing wrong?

Comment: 1 ml of water requires 4.2 watts of cooling to drop 1 degree C *in one second* as a liquid. Phase changes, e.g. from liquid to ice, need other consideration. You need to use the correct units or else your conclusions will not make sense.

Comment: 1 mL requires 4.186 joules to change it by 1 degC. Not a good start to your question.

Comment: When you say Qc is 100W and it does not say if its per hour or per minute, W are Joules per second so how can you have that per minute or hour?

Comment: The missing part of your Physics is simply thermal resistance. . Your calculation assumes no energy is transferred out or power integrated over time or time constant due to Rth and heat mass. whereas the purpose is to maximize thermal conductance and still create the temperature difference albeit with low efficiency to transfer heat power from one part to outside the “system”. Your calculation is a closed system. With no conductance or thermal resistance. I think, but maybe I didn’t explain correctly

Comment: Andrew - DUH! You get to hit me in the head the the hammer! It takes much more to phase change. And we do get 0c quickly

Andy - also correct, but to simplify and the fact it is water, W and J are almost interchangeable

TheAndy - Exactly our point, and pointing out that many devices will list W per hour or such. sorry for lack of clarity

Comment: Sunny - most of this is done for us in the peltier design.

Comment: No bitcoin, it is done by the external thermal conductance and the Peltier/Seebeck design effects of a system, ideally the temperature difference dT should be zero for max Q transfer. so the system Rth matters on both sides of the interface, limited by surface area

Comment: Sunny - true, but how does that change our setup?

Comment: By your choice of Rth for thermal resistance or 1/conductance and then insulation of the target device to be cooled to maximize dQ/dT. **active device interfaces** need very low Rth and **passive targets need low temp with very high Rth on the outside** to minimize cooling losses to ambient

Comment: W and J are not interchangeable.

Comment: the system design is to cool a target by low Rth to both sides of active Peltier device and then high Rth to the target being cooled on one side while trying to avoid absorbing heat energy outside from a warmer ambient with high Rth

Comment: "*W and J are almost interchangeable*". No they're not, just as km/h is not interchangeable with km. You might get the same *numerical* value for each *if* the integration time is one unit of time measurement but the units are certainly not interchangeable. Tips: Use HTML entity `&deg;` for the ° symbol and capital 'C' for celcius (lowercase when spelled out, as are all SI units named after a person).

Comment: So it is all about Rth ratios for active and passive interfaces to maximize dQ/dT and the mass affects this time constant at low power. consider that a CPU cooler takes <10 seconds to stabilize CPU interface temp while the PC enclosure ambient inside takes 30 minute to reach equilibrium , why? Same reasons

Comment: High conductance on the cooler interface and high resistance and heat mass on the box air and MOBO

Comment: this should tell you that you can improve a CPU cooler by removing the heat directly outside the box rather than circulating it inside the box as most do which is the same warm air used to cool the CPU with fan and heatsink only. this can make a 10 to 15’C difference in many PC towers on the CPU temp if at 60’C The case fans are not faster than the CPU fans so the heat often rises inside the box 10 to 15’C. For Peltier on a CPU, you must remove all heat outside the box to get this advantage with water cooling or stacking 2 or more Peltier in series and same heat transfer outside the system

Comment: OK, OK, I asked for all this... can I narrow the scope now?

Take a TEC1-12715 set up with the cold side operating at -17c, the hot side having tons of capacity to absorb more heat, the cold side connected to a metal 40cl beaker and the empty beaker reaches 0 degrees in less than a minute. Is there some reason it won't make ice if plain water is added to the beaker? IE - come on... this isn't rocket surgery. Should it work or not, please? 'cause it aint =)

Comment: Update your question with assumptions to Rth for each interface please. I used to be a Rocket Scientist in the 70’s and we always used specs.  With a simple model or block diagram of Thevenin resistors and a power source with some efficiency

Comment: Don’t use terms like “well-cooled”. How well ? What value?  What is the specific heat? What is insulation to ambient?